# Detect touch action that involves status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar, nsnotificationcenter

I have to perform action when user returns from expanded status bar.
What I can do:
1. User touches status bar. using this code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onStop)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

How to detect this action:
2.  Returning from status bar?
This method doesn't work

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(onStart)
                                                 name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.

Use 
`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`

instead of

`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` .